# cannot restart php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, configuration, php-fpm

I've made some changes in the .ini files and wanted to restart php5-fpm.

> /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
>
> Jan 20 14:25:48.171577 [ERROR] bind() for address
> '/var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock' failed: Address already in use (98)

How can I find out what is using this address? I've already stopped nginx but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lsof

```
lsof /var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock
```

The output is lines containing the information

COMMAND, PID, USER, FD, TYPE, DEVICE, SIZE/OFF, NODE, NAME e.g.

```
lsof /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
COMMAND  PID USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    2240 iain mem    REG  253,0    65928 142129 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
bash    4700 iain mem    REG  253,0    65928 142129 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
```

Comment: good idea, but I received a blank linke for /var/lib/php5-fpm/apps.sock, so it's actually not in use...but by restarting fpm it breaks with the same error :/

Comment: @32bitfloat: You are running the restart as root/through sudo aren't you ?

Comment: ah damn it, I forgot that. Thanks. I received three times php5-fpm with different IDs, seems I've got to kill some

Comment: to your edit: I was not trying to restart fpm without root privileges (did you edit your previous comment? I read about not running netstat or lsof as root, on which I replied) It was (and is) a problem with php-fpm which runs as different processes, and it seems they are all accessing this file, so it could not restart.